# put variable from vb or from javascript element into onclientclick aspx

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

this is the date data textbox in aspx

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="datepicker" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox> &emsp;
```

what i want to do is when i click the button a dialog confirmation box show the word like this

> *"No delivery for  '12/4/2017'  , are sure want to save the record ?  "*
>
> ```
>                    Ok Cancel
> ```

now this is at button in same aspx file

```
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpNoDelivery" 
      Text="No Delivery" 
      OnClientClick="return confirm('No delivery for "+ <%=datepicker.text %> +" Are you sure you want To save record')" />
```

and this is at the back vb

```
Protected Sub btnUpNoDelivery_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpNoDelivery.Click



        If datepicker.Text <> "" Then

            Dim lCnn As New SqlConnection
            Dim lCmd As New SqlCommand
            Dim lsCmd As String
            Dim lRd As SqlDataReader

            lCnn.ConnectionString = gsConnString
            lCnn.Open()
            lCmd.Connection = lCnn

            lsCmd = " INSERT INTO edrsDB..tbl_status"
            lsCmd &= " VALUES ('" & Session("SsionCode") & "'"
            lsCmd &= ", 'N.D'"
            lsCmd &= ", " & SQLQUOTE(Trim(datepicker.Text)) & ")"
            lCmd.CommandText = lsCmd
            lRd = lCmd.ExecuteReader
            Dim message As String = "alert('You has been Updated at date " & SQLQUOTE(Trim(datepicker.Text)) & "As No delivery')"
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(TryCast(sender, Control), Me.GetType(), "alert", message, True)
            lRd.Close()
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

        Else
            lblDateError.Visible = True
            lblDateError.Text = "* Pick a date."
        End If
    End Sub
```

i also have this error

> Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the
>   containing type or one of its base types

how to make it to make the date can be show at the dialog box?

Comment: Check if this line `Private WithEvents btnUpNoDelivery As Button` exists in designer code ([PageName].aspx.designer.vb). If it exists, try to bind the `OnClick` handler on that `Button` control or use `AddHandler` if required.

Comment: example addhandler? @TetsuyaYamamoto